# Cronjob in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

Create a cronjob in ruby on rails by using whenever gem.

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log" , :standard => "log/cron_log.log" }
every '* * * * * ' do
   command "puts 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end
```

Also update crontab it also add in list of crontab. But when I test it manually by

```
/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb
```

it gives error

```
/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 19: every: command not found
/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 20: puts 'you can use raw cron syntax too': command not found
/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 21: end: command not found
```

It doesn't work properly, how can I solve it

Comment: When you are testing manually, the script doesn't know where the `every` function is coming from. Rails will autoload your gems and not make you to use a `require` statement to include to gem. If you want to test manually by running the script, you will need to include the `require` statement that brings the gem into scope.

Comment: Did you start the server after installing the Gem.. I hope you didn't.

Comment: Justin any other way of testing it?

Comment: Arup already restart the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, there are a few approaches to run scheduled tasks in a Rails environment, e.g. `script/runner` and `Rake` etc., among them, rake approach is super easy and convenient and also supported by popular deployment platforms like heroku.

To define a rake task, you have a create a file in the `lib/tasks` directory of your Rails app: `lib/tasks/my_cron.rake` and define the task simply like this:

```
task :my_cron => :environment do
  puts "doing stuff...."
  SomeClass.do_some_stuff
  puts "done."
end
```

Then, to run this rake task, you can just run this rake command from the command line:

```
rake my_cron
```

You can run: `rake -T` command to see all the available rake tasks in your Rails application if you provide a `desc` to the rake task like this:

```
desc 'Running my cron task...'  
task :my_cron => :environment do
  puts "doing stuff...."
  SomeClass.do_some_stuff
  puts "done."
end
```

then, when you run this: `rake -T`, this rake task will show up in the rake taska list!

These rake tasks can be very easily scheduled on heroku using [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

When rake task works pretty well, there can be situations where you may want to process a lot of jobs in background, in those situations couple of most popular ruby gems [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) can be used, depending on your need.

Comment: Thanksss........one thing more, I see in one exampe they use namespace in task. Can you tell me what its purpose?

Comment: `namespace` are basically used to group and organize several tasks. For example, if you hit `rake -T` in any of your Rails application's directory, you will see different rake tasks like `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`, `rake db:drop` etc. tasks. These are all db related tasks and grouped under under the same namespace `db`. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving your ruby commands/scripting to a rake task.

That way you can test that the ruby command works properly via rake, i.e. ruby stuff is taken care of by rake.

Then you only need to run the rake command in the cron job. So you don't need to test cron which is a pain in the butt.